# Can't get target div with php curl from flarum

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get latest article from flarum.org but it doesn't get posts. It works other normal sites, but doesn't work in flarum.

Here is my function:

```
function questions() {

    $url = 'https://discuss.flarum.org/';

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );

    // SSL support
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' ] );

    // Variable support
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

    $result = curl_exec( $curl );

    //echo $result;

    $result = str_replace( array( "\n", "\t", "\r" ), null, $result );

    preg_match_all( '#<div class="DiscussionListItem">(.*?)</div>#', $result, $match );

    print_r( $match );

    curl_close( $curl );

}
```

This function prints an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how to parse HTML. Instead, use an HTML parser. Something like this would work, if there were any matching elements in the HTML:

```
$url = "https://discuss.flarum.org/";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$dom = new DomDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$results = $xpath->query("//div[@class='DiscussionListItem']");
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result->nodeValue;
}
```

Of course, there aren't any matching elements in the HTML. You might be better off modifying the XPath query to `//div[@class='container']/ul/li/a` instead.

Comment: It prints empty area.

Comment: If you look at the contents of the HTML, you won't find anything that matches that classname.

Comment: It gets only titles. I am begginer. Can you show me how to get titles and links? I need only this. Thank you.